# I am facing issue while runnning app and creating builds "Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED"

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Hi i am facing this issue while trying to run app and while generating builds. Can anyone please guide me through issue.

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
> Android gradle plugin: 4.1.0
> Gradle: 6.7

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/milanshrestha/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
> > Java heap space

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/android-build-failure-common-issue-failed-to-install-the-app-error-command-f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native app not running without doing anything in the previous working code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74325532/react-native-app-not-running-without-doing-anything-in-the-previous-working-code)