# Native React - VS Studio Code - npm run android - Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, react-native-cli

I have been getting this error when trying to run npm android build on my native react project. I have gone through the entire android setup along with updating Environment variables. The emulator works but the install fails with the following message:

```
     What went wrong:                                                                                                                                    
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.                                                                                               
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-android-0.72.6-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.6) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\BenTo\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\react-android\0.72.6\2e2db118c9084b05c1a5d6079148bc983668f372\react-android-0.72.6-debug.aar.
```

build.gradle as follows:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33

    // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
    classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
}
```

}

I have also run react doctor, it shows the following:

```
    Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0

Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.
```

When I press e to resolve, it shows the issues was fixed and to restart. When I restart I get the same error.

Please help.

Comment: I don't know how some users post something IDE/Editor based related. Buddy, this issue doesn't have any relation to VSCode at all. Please remove ` - VS Studio Code -` from the title. Also, the title should be specifically a title of the issue and then the explanation must be in the post not in the title. So, please remove ` - npm run android -` too. And at last, by your `react-native-doctor` results it's obvious your system hasn't got SDK. Install it and try to run it again.

Comment: Is "./gradlew clean" command work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer you are looking for
[React Native app not running without doing anything in the previous working code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74325532/react-native-app-not-running-without-doing-anything-in-the-previous-working-code?rq=1)

Try checking the SDK version in your android studio settings, Click on SDK Manager, and then SDK tools, and then click on Show Package Details and check if you have ticked 33.0.0 which is required for android development and is mentioned in the development environment setup of react native as well.

Link - https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Also few steps

1. run ./gradlew clean and then ./gradlew assembleDebug in the android folder of your project to clean gradle cache
2. Now run ./gradlew build to build android folder and then if it is successful you should be able to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project on Android studio And follow these steps

> Click `Tools` on Android Studio nav bar

> Click  `SDK Manager`

> Go on `Languages and Frameworks` and click `Android SDK`

> Then select `Android API 34` and `Android 13.0` or you can check that what's your mobile **OS** version and select also that one.

> And click `Apply` it will install that SDK for you.

After this you show clean your gradle by using `./gradlew clean` command and then you can run your project it definately run your project on your mobile.